# How to include one vie file into another view file in laravel 8?

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-blade

I am very new to the laravel view files ,i have two view files `header.blade.php` and `users.blade.php` , i want to include the header.blade.php file into the users.blade.php but it's throwing an following error how to resolve this issue..

```
include(resources/views/header.blade.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory (View: /home/resources/views/users.blade.php)
```

**users.blade.php**

```
<?php include('resources/views/header.blade.php');?>
<style type="text/css">
.plinks{
  margin-left:30%;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;
}

.plinks a {
margin-left: 10px;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;
text-decoration: none !important;
color: #212529 !important;

}
.plinks strong {
    background: #2a316a;
    padding: 1px 7px 1px 7px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #ffF;
    font-weight:500;
    font-size:15px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
</style>
      <!-- partial -->
      <div class="main-panel">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
           <div class="row mb-4 align-items-center">
                <div class="col-12 col-xl-8 mb-xl-0">
                  <h3 class="font-weight-bold mb-0">Users</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 col-xl-4 text-right">
                  <button onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo base_url();?>add_user'" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon-text">
                    <i class="ti-plus btn-icon-prepend"></i>
                    Add New Users
                  </button>
                </div>

            </div>
          <div class="row">
            <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg');?>
            <div class="col-md-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-borderless">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>User ID</th>
                          <th>Name</th>
                          <th>Creation Date</th>
                          <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <?php foreach($userlist as $user){ ?>
                        <tr>
                          <td><?php echo $user->user_id;?></td>
                          <td><a><?php echo $user->name;?></a></td>
                          <td><?php echo $user->created_date;?></td>
                          <td style="display:inline-flex;">


                           <!--  <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>user/user_details/<?php echo $user->user_id;?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-fw mr-2" id="dropdownMenuSizeButton3">View Details</a> -->

                            <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>user/deleteuser/<?php echo $user->user_id;?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="dropdownMenuSizeButton3" onClick="return doconfirm();">Delete User</a>
                            </button>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      <?php } ?>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                          <div class="plinks"><?php echo $links;?></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- content-wrapper ends -->
        <!-- partial:partials/_footer.html -->
        <footer class="footer">
          <div class="d-sm-flex justify-content-center justify-content-sm-between">
            <span class="text-muted text-center text-sm-left d-block d-sm-inline-block">Copyright © 2021.</span>
          </div>
        </footer>
        <!-- partial -->
      </div>
      <!-- main-panel ends -->
    </div>
    <!-- page-body-wrapper ends -->
  </div>
<?php include('footer.php');?>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doconfirm(){
  let del=confirm("Are you sure to delete permanently?");
  if(del!=true){
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Laravel's document provides documentation for how to use the [`@include`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#including-subviews) directive in your Blade files. Why are you using the standard `include()` function instead of that?

Comment: This code is done in the codeignitor ,i am just copying the code into laravel and i am trying to make changes in laravel code.
is there any way to include codeigniter view files into laravel folder @KirkBeard

Comment: That’s pretty important information you should have included in your question. Laravel’s Blade templates won’t work if you don’t adapt your code to suit Laravel. You’ll need to ensure you’re passing the correct data from Laravel’s controllers to the Blade files. I can also see you’re trying to use CodeIgniter sessions and helper functions in the templates, which won’t work.

Answer (score 1):

Just give the foldername dot filename like

```
@include('header')
```

considering the header.blade.php is in a folder called header inside the views folder.